# custom simple_form input date_flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Trying to use `f.input(:activated_at, as: :date_flag)` to render as a checkbox, which sends down `Time.now` for true and `nil` for false.

https://github.com/postageapp/date_flag/blob/master/lib/date_flag.rb
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcombo/simple_form/main/lib/simple_form/inputs/boolean_input.rb

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DateFlagInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options = {})
    template.content_tag(:div, class: "form-check form-switch") do
      template.concat(@builder.check_box(attribute_name, {class: 'form-check-input'}, Time.now, nil))
      template.concat(template.label(attribute_name, label_text, {class: "form-check-label"}))
    end
  end
end
```

This code above gets me a bootstrap5 checkbox, which sends down the time, but cannot render a "checked".

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out!

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DateFlagInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput
  def input(wrapper_options = {})
    flag_value = object.send(attribute_name)
    # date_flag magic
    input_html_options[:checked] = flag_value ? (flag_value <= Time.now) : false

    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)
    merged_input_options[:class] = [input_html_classes]

    template.content_tag(:div, class: container_class_name) do
      build_hidden_field_for_checkbox +
          build_check_box_without_hidden_field(merged_input_options) +
          @builder.label(label_target, label_text, {class: boolean_label_class})
    end
  end

  def label_translation
    if SimpleForm.translate_labels && (translated_label = translate_from_namespace(:labels))
      translated_label
    elsif object.class.respond_to?(:human_attribute_name)
      object.class.human_attribute_name(reflection_or_attribute_name.to_s.gsub(/_at$/, ''))
    else
      attribute_name.to_s.gsub(/_at$/, '').humanize.titleize
    end
  end

  def container_class_name
    "form-check"
  end

  def label(wrapper_options)
    template.label_tag(nil, '&nbsp;'.html_safe)
  end

  def input_html_classes
    'form-check-input'
  end

  def boolean_label_class
    "form-check-label"
  end

  def checked_value
    Time.now
  end

  def unchecked_value
    0
  end
end
```

1. adding the `checked:`  option to show how the checkbox should render.
2. the `unchecked_value` cannot be `nil` because nil does gets excluded from the params. using `nil` or `0` both worked for the `unchecked_value`!